# Run function over dataframe with columns of differing length after dropna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, variable-length

I am trying to apply the following function over each column in a dataframe:

```
def hurst_lag(x):
    minlag = 200
    maxlag = 300
    lags = range(minlag, maxlag)
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(x.dropna()[lag:], x.dropna()[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]
    m = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)
    return m[0]*2
```

The function only works on non NA values. In my dataframe, the lengths of my columns differ after applying dropna(). e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA':[None, None, 1, 2], 
    'colB': [None, 2, 6, 4],
    'colC': [None, None, 2, 8],
    'colD': [None, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
})
```

Any ideas how to run the  function over each column individually, excluding the NA values for that specific column?  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` to run it on the dataframe

```
df = df.apply(hurst_lag)
```

Comment: Hi resolved it using hurst_lag(df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna()), axis=0)). Many thanks

Comment: I was thinking `lamda` a little after i posted that. Glad you were able to get it sorted.